# Why when i change my like Price and Time my dynamoDb like Update not add the new one?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Hi all i got error when i want to insert data to my dynamoDb like this

in my code i have add the Symbol. and here my code

```
public class InsertData {

    static AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com", "us-east-2"))
            .build();
    static DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    static String tableName = "PriceOneZero";
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Call CreateItem");
        createItems();
}
    private static void createItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
        System.out.println("runFirstTime For Insert Data");
        try{
            String symbols= "USDJPY";
            String price = "100.89";
            String time = "2020-06-05T00:00:02.111";

            //Add Content 
            Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("Symbol", symbols).withString("Price", price).withString("Time", time);
            //save to DynamoDb
            table.putItem(item);
            System.out.println("Success For Insert Data");


        }catch (AmazonDynamoDBException e) {
            System.err.println("Create items failed.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           }
    }
}
```

when i use that code in my database there is only have data

Symbol :USDJPY 
Price : 100.89
Time : 2020-06-05T00:00:02.111

after that i try to change my code become

public class InsertData {

```
    static AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com", "us-east-2"))
            .build();
    static DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    static String tableName = "PriceOneZero";
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Call CreateItem");
        createItems();
}
    private static void createItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
        System.out.println("runFirstTime For Insert Data");
        try{
            String symbols= "USDJPY";
            String price = "100.89";
            String time = "2020-06-05T00:00:02.112";

            //Add Content 
            Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("Symbol", symbols).withString("Price", price).withString("Time", time);
            //save to DynamoDb
            table.putItem(item);
            System.out.println("Success For Insert Data");


        }catch (AmazonDynamoDBException e) {
            System.err.println("Create items failed.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           }
    }
}
```

the diffirent is in Time from .111 become .112

and in my dynamoDb Database my data only like update that not add so i only have one data like
Symbol :USDJPY 
Price : 100.89
Time : 2020-06-05T00:00:02.111

not like this
Symbol Price time 
USDJPY 100.89 2020-06-05T00:00:02.111
USDJPY 100.89 2020-06-05T00:00:02.112

why like that ?

my question why there is any error ? and how to fix it ?

regards,

Fuad

Comment: Are You sure that your PriceOneZero table has a primary key with `Symbols` as name?

Comment: okay i will check first in my table and update here again

Comment: You have typo `Symbols`. just use `Symbol` without "S" in java code.

Comment: this was clear... yes i got typo without "s" and other problem is when i change my code for each attribute in my database like update from the symbol not add the new one why like that ?

Comment: AFAIS You want to have two elements in DB, but You have one after putItem. The reason for that is - you update the same row with a primary key `USDJPY`. You can use `secondary key` with `time` and this will resolve your problem.

Comment: all right i have test to use add id. thanks all. it is clear now for this question